# Arabic to Greek numeral converter, 1 - 10

Tags: javascript, integer, number-systems

One of the things that's straight-forward in JavaScript is Unicode support. If you want to return `ϝ` (lowercase digamma, not a simple `f`), you simply tell it to do so. No look-up, conversion or unreadable Unicode codes required.

I want to build a translator between Arabic and Greek numerals. Since my projects tend to take forever to complete, I decided to post what I have instead of waiting till it's finished. The code currently supports 1 - 10 and translates them to the Unicode Greek equivalent.

I wrote it the most straight-forward way I could think of. It's not necessarily the best way.

```
function arabicToGreek(input) {
    'use strict';
    switch (input) {
    case 1:
        return "α";
    case 2:
        return "β";
    case 3:
        return "γ";
    case 4:
        return "δ";
    case 5:
        return "ε";
    case 6:
        return "ϝ";
    case 7:
        return "ζ";
    case 8:
        return "η";
    case 9:
        return "θ";
    case 10:
        return "ι";
    }
    return "";  
}
```

Usage:

```
arabicToGreek(4);    
arabicToGreek(10);
```

Output:

```
δ
ι
```

[Run it at repl.it](https://repl.it/BeGX/0)

I'm aware `ϝ` (6) should possibly be written as `ϛ`. I'm also aware I may or may not need to include diacritics.

I'm especially looking for a review on the usual suspects: naming, idiomatic style and modularity. All other advice is welcome as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's great to see that you're using strict mode for strict compliance (which should really be the default), however you shouldn't use strict mode *the way you are now*. You've probably seen strict mode placed inside of functions, but those functions are IIFEs (Immediately Invoked Function Expressions) - it looks a bit like this.

```
(function() {
  'use strict'
}())
```

The reasoning behind why we encapsulate `'use strict'` inside of a function is pretty simple: `'use strict'` switches on strict compliance for *all* scripts in the same execution scope that the directive is executed in that are loaded after the directive.

In English, what that means is if you don't encapsulate the `'use strict'` directive inside of a function, any script loaded after the script that initially uses `'use strict'` will have strict compliance turned on as well. Some scripts (unfortunately) are not written with strict compliance in mind and will promptly throw their toys out of the pram if this happens.

So why do I not recommend putting it in `arabicToGreek`? Well, strict mode is *a good thing* (and should be standard), so it'd be better to just define it once per project. For larger projects that use things like Babel, strict mode is automatically applied; for smaller projects, you should just wrap your entire project in an IIFE that has the `'use strict'` directive to prevent yourself from having to redefine it all of the time.

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  function arabicToGreek(input) {
    ...
  }
}())
```

Note, if you're using Node, each module is already implicitly wrapped in an IIFE, so you can use `'use strict'` in each file just fine.

---

You'd need to be an electrician to maintain that many switches! As suggested by [Quill](http://insertlinkhere.com), you can use an object instead of a large switch statement, which is what I would do:

```
const characterMap = {
  1: 'α',
  2: 'β'
}

function arabicToGreek(code) {
  return characterMap[code]
}
```

Of course, this looks a *bit* like an array, so that could work too, but given that the index of the character is important here I would prefer to use an object just for clarity.

I don't agree with the idea of using `hasOwnProperty` here; if a character doesn't exist in the `characterMap` object, then attempting to access that property is just going to return `undefined`. JavaScript [has another alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and) for absent values called `null`.

The way I like to see the difference is this: `undefined` is a value that *hasn't been defined*; `null` is a value that *has* been defined as explicitly being absent. As a result, in this instance, I would check to see whether or not the expression `characterMap[code]` evaluates `undefined` and, if it does, return `null` instead.

```
function arabicToGreek(code) {
  const character = characterMap[code]
  if(character === undefined) {
    return null
  }
  return character
}
```

If we abuse the fact that `undefined`, `null`, `0` and `false` all evaluate `false` in JavaScript (also known as "falsey"), this can be shortened using the logical OR operator (`||`) to look like this:

```
function arabicToGreek(code) {
  return characterMap[code] || null
}
```

---

Note that in all examples I've used above I've used `const`. `const` is a keyword introduced in ES6 that essentially ensures that the identifier can be assigned to once *and only once*. Attempting to reassign it will cause a runtime error.

If you're running this code in an ES5 browser that doesn't support ES6, you'll run into issues because (ironically), `'use strict'` breaks `const` prior to ES6 - in ES5, `const` was a reserved keyword that didn't actually do anything - same thing as `class`. In ES6 these were both codified into actual concepts in the spec. They should work fine on any reasonably modern browser, though, and in any of the newer versions of Node.

As an alternative to using an Object, you may be interested in the ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is a fairly close analogue to a Dictionary from C# or a Map from Java. Key benefits include `Map` not having a `prototype` (no need to do `hasOwnProperty`), keys can be any value (keys in objects are implicitly converted to a string - or `Symbol`), and retrieving the `length` of a `Map` is actually possible without sacrificing your soul to Zalgo.

Comment: I find your lack of semicolons disturbing...

Comment: @Kroltan haha, I prefer to not use them :P

Comment: Is "I prefer to not use them" only a joke? If not, I'm curious and interested to know your reasons.

Comment: @cFreed [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). I feel that the semi colons are just noise; one statement on one line is enough for ASI to know where statements start/end. The only places I feel I need to use semicolons are where the statements are ambigious - for example, in a `for` loop. It also doesn't [break minification](http://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/), so it is largely a stylistic choice - as long as are aware of places where things *are* ambigious.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link. But it enforces my astonishment: it seems to me that the concern to avoid errors (and BTW increase readability) would lead to prefer using semicolons systematically. I find this type of choice is equivalent to the one about using blocks where they are not mandatory with `if()`, `for()` and so on. But actually, sure it"s a stylistic choice, as you stated.

Comment: @cFreed I figure that the cases where it causes issues are so rare (as long as you code in a normal manner) that it doesn't really matter; consistency is the key either way.

Answer (score 13):

Reviewing your current structure: your `return "";` could be improved: it should / could be inside the `switch` statement as a `default` case.

---

It's better to use an object here, as later you can extend it without having to spend pointless LoCs on `case`s and `break`ing.

```
function arabicToGreek(input) {
    'use strict';
    var greek = {
        1: "α",
        2: "β",
        3: "γ",
        4: "δ",
        5: "ε",
        6: "ϝ",
        7: "ζ",
        8: "η",
        9: "θ",
        10: "ι"
    };
    //
}
```

Then, add `greek.hasOwnProperty` to check that your string is a valid object property, in which case that it isn't, you can throw an error.

```
if (!greek.hasOwnProperty(input)){
    throw new Error("input not a valid integer representing a character");
}
```

This also means you can store the greek characters and potentially other languages in an external JSON document.

Comment: This would definitely solve part of the maintainability issues. Thanks :-)

Comment: `'use strict'` should not be inside of `arabicToGreek`. If you want to restrict what is `'use strict'`, then wrap the entire code file in an IIFE. You run the risk of weird compatibility errors between functions if some functions are strict-mode and others are not. I wouldn't `throw` in the event of an unknown character; I would instead return `null` to indicate the absence of a corresponding value.

Answer (score 10):

That looks like a classic case for a lookup table.  This function should be a one-liner.

We know that parameters are inputs.  What kind of input?  Also, the input isn't Arabic; it's just abstractly a number.  It would be better to rename the parameter and function to `number`.

```
function numberToGreek(number) {
    return "αβγδεϝζηθι".charAt(number - 1);
}
```

Comment: That's definitely the most straight-forward way to do it. An eye-opener, I hadn't considered doing it like this before.

Comment: This is a cool idea, but the reason I didn't suggest it is because you @Mast may not have wanted to have the entire map rely on implicit ordering.

Comment: @DanPantry Now both options are explained I can figure out what fits best. Thanks to you both.

Comment: Be wary when using native JS methods on strings that may contain unicode - some characters (e.g. those above `U+FFFF`) are stored and interpreted as two 16-bit characters, giving misleading results.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use anything other than a string to express this - in general sequential translations could be encoded as string index lookup

```
function arabicToGreek(input) {
    return " αβγδεϝζηθι"[input];
}
```

Or in ES2015:

```
let arabicToText => i => " αβγδεϝζηθι"[i];
```

Comment: The difference is that your `arabicToGreek(0)` returns a Space, whereas mine returns an empty string like the original code.